# Retrieve App Store ID in Native iOS Apps

Tags: ios

In my apps I want to retrieve/read the App Store ID. is there an api or webservice via which I can get App Store ID given to my app? I am talking about Native iOS applications.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really an API to do it. But you can get it right off of the ITC website.